# Using UIActivityIndicator-for-SDWebImage with Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, sdwebimage, bridging-header

I'm using `SDWebImage` and I would like to add a loading indicator. I found the `UIActivityIndicator-for-SDWebImage` library, and I have tried to add it to my Swift project by adding this:

```
#import "UIImageView+UIActivityIndicatorForSDWebImage.h"
```

to my bridging header. For some reason I still can't access the extra parameter `usingActivityIndicatorStyle` when setting image URLs.

Anyone have any idea what I'm doing wrong? I've tried removing the .m and .h files and re-adding them, but it didn't help.

Answer (score 4):

1. Add "use_frameworks!" in the Podfile

   ```
   use_frameworks!

   target '<YOUR TARGET>' do
   .........
       pod 'UIActivityIndicator-for-SDWebImage'
   .........
   end
   ```
2. In "Pods -> UIActivityIndicator-for-SDWebImage -> UIImageView+UIActivityIndicatorForSDWebImage.h" replace:

   ```
   #import "UIImageView+WebCache.h"
   #import "SDImageCache.h"
   ```

   With:

   ```
   #import <SDWebImage/UIImageView+WebCache.h>
   #import <SDWebImage/SDImageCache.h>
   ```
3. In "AppDelegate.swift" add

   ```
   import UIActivityIndicator_for_SDWebImage
   ```

   That's all.

P.S. You should correct Pods because author of UIActivityIndicator-for-SDWebImage wrote in description: "... I really don't want to keep this repo updated ...", and he really doesn't do it.

Comment: Will #import <SDWebimage/SDImageCache.h> also work on pure Objective-C project?  If so, I think the pod should update to this one so it works on both Objective-C and Swift.

Comment: Sure, this pod wrote on Objective C and will work on both Objective-C and Swift projects.

Comment: I know this pod works on both Obj-C and Swift project.  But the #import "SDImageCache.h" doesn't - we must unlock the file and modify it to #import <...>.  However, on a pod update or reinstall, it revert to the git version.  So, if "..." works for Obj-C only but <...> works on both, it is better to use <...> over "..."

Comment: UIImageView+UIActivityIndicatorForSDWebImage.h, where changes should be done is Objective C file. Sure, on pod update changes will reverted. As this pod is not supported more, one way to prevent this is to create own fork and use it.

Answer (score 3):

**Swift 3 & SDWebImage 4.0.0**

This will do the trick, try this code

```
        let urlString = URL(string: "Your image URL")
        yourImageView.sd_setIndicatorStyle(.gray)
        yourImageView.sd_setShowActivityIndicatorView(true)
        yourImageView.sd_setImage(with: urlString) { (loadedImage, error, cacheType, url) in
            yourImageView.sd_removeActivityIndicator()
            if error != nil {
                print("Error code: \(error!.localizedDescription)")
            } else {
                yourImageView.image = loadedImage
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer above works

Follow this issue https://github.com/JJSaccolo/UIActivityIndicator-for-SDWebImage/pull/28

You will find a fork which has made this update

https://github.com/masterfego/UIActivityIndicator-for-SDWebImage

I forked it too,

https://github.com/useeless37/UIActivityIndicator-for-SDWebImage

then in your pod file

```
pod 'UIActivityIndicator-for-SDWebImage', :git => 'https://github.com/useeless37/UIActivityIndicator-for-SDWebImage.git'
```